# Struggling to display blob image with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, blob

I am building a simple website, I want to allow the users to upload and change their avatars. At present I have been able to upload images to a mysql database, stored as blobs with the code as follows:

```
//connected to DB, userID fetched

$image = $FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$fp = fopen($image, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($image));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

$sql = "UPDATE tbUsers SET profileImage = '".$content."' WHERE userID = ".userID;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

When I download the files from phpmyadmin after upload they are saved as .bin files, but can be viewed normally. I'm not sure if this is correct or not.
My code to display the images is as follows:

HTML:

```
<?php echo '<img src ="showPic.php?q='.$_SESSION['profile'].'"/>'; ?>
```

PHP:

```
if (!empty($_GET['profile']) && is_numeric($_GET['profile']))
{
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  $mysql_select_db("projectDB");
  $sql = "SELECT profileImage FROM tbUsers WHERE userID = ". $_GET['profile'];
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
  echo $row['image_data'];
}
```

I am unsure if I am attempting to display the image in the correct way, any help (corrections/alternative solutions) would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What you are doing is terribly insecure!  `addslashes()` is not sufficient for preventing SQL injection attacks and problems.  Use prepared queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem.

Comment: Don't store images on the DB, images should be on the filesystem. Insert a record to a DB of the uploaded image (user info) and use that info to store/display your image.

Comment: I disagree. There is nothing wrong with keeping images in the database. It's actually very useful. Obviously you have to cache them in filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
if (!empty($_GET['profile']) && is_numeric($_GET['profile']))
{
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  $mysql_select_db("projectDB");
  $sql = "SELECT profileImage FROM tbUsers WHERE userID = ". $_GET['profile'];
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

  $content = mysql_result($result,0,"file_content");
  $name = mysql_result($result,0,"file_name");
  $type = mysql_result($result,0,"file_type");
  $size = mysql_result($result,0,"file_size");
  header("Content-type: $type");

  echo $content

}
```

Note : You should have these column in you table where you save your BLOB data

file_name = for save filename

```
$_FILES['file']['name']
```

file_type = for save file type

```
$_FILES['file']['type']
```

file_size = for save file size

```
$_FILES['file']['size']
```

Answer (score 0):

You select this

```
$sql = "SELECT profileImage FROM tbUsers WHERE userID = ". $_GET['profile'];
```

and refer to not selected column

```
echo $row['image_data'];
```

Comment: Also, he used mysql_fetch_object means it return object not array.